# How to write ISO-C compliant code while allowing multiple instructions between sequencing points?

Tags: c, optimization, portability

I have a subtle question; I would like to write code that is portable (that's why I am sticking to any of the last three ISO-C standard definitions) and machine-independent (thus, assembler is out of the question), but that let the compiler pack several (independent) instructions within one CPU cycle.

I thought that using the comma operator would do the trick, but the standard says that each coma is a sequencing point, so it would not do.

I would like to take advantage of multiple independent assignments, additions, etc. (just as a register variable is an indication to the compiler of possible optimizations and of independentness of the operations).

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 5):

**Let the compiler do optimizations.**

The compiler can optimize across sequence points when it recognizes that they are independent and without interactions.

For example, in code:

```
a = x+y;
b = y+z;
```

A compiler can recognize that the assignment of `a` and `b` are fully independent of each other, and can do both at the same time, *despite the sequence point*.

As a general rule, *you cannot do a better job than the compiler*. 
Let the compiler do its job of creating fast, efficient code, and you should focus on your job:
***writing clear, unambiguous instructions for bug-free algorithms***.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler generates code. The processor executes it. It is up to the processor to perform more than one instruction per cycle, and modern processors are quite good at this. If operations are independent, the processor will figure it out.

The processor will also rearrange instructions, and often perform multiple instructions that are nowhere near together in your source code. There is nothing that you can do to help in source code.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is deeply misguided, as other answerers have pointed out.  (Compilers usually reorder things and do all sorts of horrible stuff even when things are separated by sequence points; conversely, doing two things that can "interfere" with one another that aren't separated by a sequence point is undefined behaviour.)  However, you *can* do what you're asking in a bit of a silly way.

The evaluation of different arguments to a function call are not sequenced with respect to one another, so you can make up a dummy function like this:

```
void dont_sequence(int, int) {}
```

and use it like this:

```
dont_sequence(i += 2, j += 4);
```

Again, I don't believe there is any purpose to this.  This won't help any compiler I've ever used.  The compiler doesn't have to follow your instructions; it's only required to generate code that behaves as if it followed your instructions, and that's what modern compilers do.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** there is no such trick available. Choose different language

**1.** C language was designed to be portable and machine-independent but does not have language constructs to clearly express data flow independence or other hints that might be utilized by compilers when targeting processors with different parallel granularity (see e.g. article [Threading and Parallel Programming Constructs used in multicore systems development: Part 2](http://www.embedded.com/design/mcus-processors-and-socs/4007127/Threading-and-Parallel-Programming-Constructs-used-in-multicore-systems-development-Part-2) for discussion of such constructs).

**2.** Abstract machine-independent compiler target (which reflects current processor architectures) was described by computer scientist Donald Knuth as [MMIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMIX). There is also GCC compiler available that can target this processor. So you might check your C code against this output

**3.** For more detail explanation of how compilers and processors derive their hints (you call them sequencing points) see e.g. book [Processor Architecture: From Dataflow to Superscalar and Beyond ; with 34 Tables - Jurij Silc, Borut Robic, Theo Ungerer](http://books.google.cz/books?id=JEYKyfZ3yF0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=isbn:3540647988&hl=en&sa=X&ei=81qJU4LdKMaIOICbgdAI&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

**3.** For list of portable and machine-independent languages that explicitly support paralelism see e.g. [Wikipedia: List of concurrent and parallel programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_concurrent_and_parallel_programming_languages)

**4.** For some discussion about how to use C for parallel programming see e.g. [Which is the best parallel programming language for initiating undergraduate students in the world of multicore/parallel computing?](http://www.researchgate.net/post/Which_is_the_best_parallel_programming_language_for_initiating_undergraduate_students_in_the_world_of_multicore_parallel_computing)